# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException exception in UNIX

Tags: java, unix

I have my java spring standalone project which works fine in windows but when I create jar file and executes that jar file by using shell script, it gives me `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`. It seems that in unix it is unable to load the beans and unable to do component scan.

I have application contex file as below:

```
<context:annotation-config /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ubs.lazar" />

<context:property-placeholder location="oracle.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${batch.jdbc.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${batch.jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${batch.jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${batch.jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="daoFactory" class="com.ubs.mzq.xen.db.XenDaoFactory">
        <property name="databaseName" value="oracle" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>     

    <tx:annotation-driven/>
```

And I am invoking and load the configuration from java as below:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:META-INF/application-context.xml");
AwardEventService awardEventService = (AwardEventService) context.getBean("awardEventServiceImpl");
```

Can you please somebody helps to how to overcome this issue in UNIX.

Thanks

Comment: do you use UTF-8 for your files? how about line endings, are they consistently `\n`? in unix component scan works just fine, so I'm suspecting these other issues have an impact. also, check your class path for identical libraries.

Comment: It's more likely that some bean failed to initialize. Then, a later (dependent) bean failed to find that first bean. Check carefully the rest of the error message.

Comment: Thanks benatespina for reply, how to check class path for identical libraries? I am using UTF-8 for the files. The issue is that it is working for windows and for unix it is not. Why this is difference? For overcome this issue, do I need to do any settings or any configuration required.